# Get the lowest value of PREVIOUS 5 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to get the lowest close price of **PREVIOUS 5 days** (Not include current position day), therefore I have the code:

```
LClose5=pd.DataFrame()
LClose5['LClose5'] = stock_store['Close'].rolling(window=5).min()
```

The result isn't what I want, if current position day close price is the lowest, it will pick it as the lowest price for last 5 days. This is incorrect.

What I really want to is compare the "current close price" vs "Previous 5 days lowest price"

Sorry I try to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: If you don't want the overall min, then remove `.min()`

Comment: If you want to exclude today, then filter the dataframe first to exclude it

Comment: can you share a sample of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `shift` to move all the values down 1 row:

`LClose5['LClose5'] = stock_store['Close'].rolling(window=5).min().shift(1)`

Here's a toy example where the 6th entry (1) is lower than the first 5 rows. The first entry in the `LClose5` column (at row 6) will be 4, since this is the minimum of the 5 rows above:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"close": [10, 9, 4, 5, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2]})
df["LClose5"] = df["close"].rolling(window=5).min().shift(1)
```

The output looks like:

```
close   LClose5
10  NaN
9   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
7   NaN
1   4.0
5   1.0
6   1.0
2   1.0
```